# Bitcoin-qt -testnet 0.17.1 Send and Receive buttons do nothing

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, testnet

Fully synced on testnet blockchain after building Bitcoin with UI and wallet enabled on Ubuntu 18.10.

Pressing Send and Receive buttons results in no UI displayed.

Receiving addresses dialog doesn't have New button in this version so it can't be used.

Debug window getnewaddress worked, however, and I was able to receive some coins from coinfaucet.eu using that address.

After receiving coins Send button still doesn't result in any UI displayed.
Receiving addresses menu/resulting dialog now shows the address that coins were received at (the one obtained via getnewaddress).

I see the same behavior of buttons when synced on the main net but couldn't test sending or receiving the real Bitcoins.

What can I do to debug this issue without getting deep into the (quite unfamiliar at this point) source code? I compiled bitcoin with optimizations enabled.

Here is a [link](https://github.com/Toninoso/various/blob/master/debug.log) to the debug.log created in the following way: exited bitcoin-qt and renamed original log which was huge. Restarted bitcoin-qt with options -testnet -debug=1. Clicked on Send, Receive and Transactions buttons. Exited bitcoin-qt.

Comment: To get addresses, you need to go to the receive tab and click the `Request Payment` button. For the sending issue, can you show a screenshot/video of what you are doing?

Comment: @AndrewChow I don't see `Request Payment` button either. This is tabbed interface? I'll try to create animated GIF but it won't show you much beside that clicking on `Send`, `Receive` and `Transaction` buttons still shows the `Overview page`.Tabs in `Debug window` work, however. This may be Ubuntu 18.10 UI specific. I'll try link to data dir from older Ubuntu install to verify that.

Comment: Clicking `Send`, `Receive`, and `Transactions` should show different pages. Can you also post your debug.log file? Using a different datadir won't make a difference. Nothing stored in the datadir effects how the UI behaves.

Comment: @AndrewChow added link to debug.log at the bottom of the post. Regarding datadir  I meant running UI from older Ubuntu but pointing to datadir on USB SSD which has Ubuntu 18.10 and where I built bitcoin-qt, to avoid downloading the blockchain from scratch.

Comment: Is this self compiled or using the official release binary from bitcoincore.org? If self compiled, what version of Qt do you have installed? (you should be able to get this from Bitcoin Core by going to Help > About Qt.

Comment: This looks like a bug and I can't find an open issue about this. Can you open an issue here: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues?

Comment: @AndrewChow thanks for sticking through this 'ordeal' with me :) Qt version is 5.11.1  and I will open an issue.

Comment: @AndrewChow this is self-compiled (after apt-get update and upgrade of fresh Ubuntu 18.10 install) and I will first `make clean` and rebuild from scratch. Then, if problem persists, open an issue.

Comment: @AndrewChow full rebuild after `make clean` helped. I see `Send`, `Receive` and `Transactions` pages now. So, what did I do wrong? Upon the initial build I had build errors with Berkeley DB. Following that I built configuring with --disable-wallet. Later, I found out BDB build problem cause and fixed it via  [link for BDB fix](https://gist.github.com/danieldk/5700533). Then I rebuilt configuring without --disable-wallet and running make again, without cleaning before that.

Without Berkeley DB build issue this would likely never happen. It may be deserving of documentation PR.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I should answer this question for the people who may stumble here and would like to know right away what is this issue all about.

If you are building from source and configure your build like:

`./configure --with-gui --disable-wallet --SOME-OTHER-OPTIONS`

and then you decide you want the wallet and go back to configure and rebuild without `--disable-wallet`, that is:

`./configure --with-gui --SOME-OTHER-OPTIONS`

make sure you run `make clean` before rebuilding.